# {{#each model}} is not listing the models

Tags: javascript, templates, model-view-controller, ember.js, model

I'm trying to display the names of each department. I handmade a 'department' model based off of another model i made that does work. Despite them being identical, #each will not loop through the 'departments' and list them.

departments.hbs >

```
{{#each model}}
 <tr>
  <td>
  {{#linkTo 'department' this}}{{this.departmentName}}{{/linkTo}}
  </td>
  <td>{{this.departmentName}}</td>
 </tr> 
{{/each}}
```

No errors. It just doesn't list the departments.

```
VpcYeoman.DepartmentsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'departments'});

VpcYeoman.DepartmentView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'department'
});

VpcYeoman.DepartmentsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // Implement your controller here.
});

VpcYeoman.Department = DS.Model.extend({
  departmentName: DS.attr('string'),
  departmentMembers: DS.attr('string')
});

VpcYeoman.Department.reopen({
  // certainly I'm duplicating something that exists elsewhere...
  attributes: function(){
      var attrs = [];
      var model = this;
      Ember.$.each(Ember.A(Ember.keys(this.get('data'))), function(idx, key){
        var pair = { key: key, value: model.get(key) };
        attrs.push(pair);
      });
      return attrs;
    }.property()
});

VpcYeoman.Department.FIXTURES = [

  {
    id: 0,
    departmentName: "Sickness",
    departmentMembers: "61"
  },

  {
    id: 1,
    departmentName: "Health",
    departmentMembers: "69"
  }

];
```

'department/#/' DOES work. Why is {{#each model}} not able to find the list of departments?

EDIT:

```
VpcYeoman.DepartmentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  // Implement your controller here.
});
```

Upon entering {{log model}} before the {{#each model)) loop, I get this response:

```
    [nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function, getEach: function…]
    __ember1386699686611_meta: Meta
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]

VpcYeoman.DepartmentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
  }
});

VpcYeoman.DepartmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

Comment: Can you show the model hook for the departments route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DepartmentsController should probably be an ArrayController, and you can view the model in the console to validate it has something using `((log model))` before your each

You need to implement a model hook, returning the departments

```
VpcYeoman.DepartmentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('department');
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

the department route is guessing based on the route name and implementing the default model hook.

Comment: {{log model}} yields the error in the EDIT: above. I see no reason why this should not grab the proper models '/department/#' does bring me to specific departments.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a `DepartmentsRoute` with the following:

```
VpcYeoman.DepartmentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('department');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the problem-  You have not defined a route.  Normally, the controller will proxy 'model' to the route, so I would create the DepartmentsRoute and a DepartmentsController that extends ArrayController.  Then, in your template, you can just say {{#each}}.

Comment: Although I have marked kingpin's solution as correct, this also works!